# Rails return locations near current location with Geocoder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

I'm using geocoder with my rails app and trying to return a list of Parks near my current location. The code below is working but of course just returns the parks their distance from a given park (current object).  Just not sure how to do this vs current location.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code used in the View:

```
<% @parks.each do |park| %>
<%park.nearbys(1.9).each do |near_park| %>
<li><%= link_to near_park.name%> (<%= near_park.distance.round(2)%> kms)</li>
<% end %>
```

controller setup:

```
 class SearchController < ApplicationController

   def new
    @parks = Park.all
    @activities = Activity.all
   end

   def address
    @address = Park.find(params[:address])
    Geocode.search("@address")
   end
```

end

Initializer:

```
 Geocoder.configure(

# geocoding service:
:lookup => :google,

# IP address geocoding service:
:ip_lookup => :maxmind,

# to use an API key:
:api_key => 'API KEY',

# this is very important option for configuring geocoder with API key
:use_https => true,

# geocoding service request timeout, in seconds (default 3):
:timeout => 3,

# set default units to kilometers:
:units => :km,
 )
```

Model:

```
Class Park < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :park_activities
  has_many :activities, through: :park_activities
  has_many :events, through: :park_activities

  validates :name, :address, presence: true

  # accepts_nested_attributes_for :activities
  geocoded_by :address       # can also be an IP address
  after_validation :geocode, :if => :address_changed?

end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class ParksController
  def nearby
    @parks = Park.near([params.fetch(:lng){ 0 }, params.fetch(:lon){ 0 }], params.fetch(:radius){ 20 })
  end
end
```

To get the users position you can either use geolocation in the client (when using ajax) or an [IP lookup](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#geocoding-service-lookup-configuration) on the server.

```
# ip based lookup example.
class ParksController
  def nearby
    @location = request.location
    if @location
      @parks = Park.near(@location)
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Location not available"
      @parks = Park.all
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the response Max.  I'm a beginner so please bare with me.   I'm not understanding how to do the IP lookup on the server.  The initializer is configured to use  :ip_lookup => :maxmind but I don't know how to utilize it.

Comment: You can use  `request.location` which will return nil or a `Geocoder::Result` object.